# Double pendulum animation

Tags: maple

I'm trying to obtain animated double pendulum. Though I can obtain animation for any (one) mass, I can't obtain it for both.

```
restart; 
with(DEtools, odeadvisor); 
with(plots); 
with(plottools); 
Sys := [2*(diff(T1(t), t, t))+cos(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T2(t), t, t))+sin(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T2(t), t))^2+19.6*sin(T1(t)) = 0, diff(T2(t), t, t)+cos(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T1(t), t, t))-sin(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T1(t), t))+9.8*sin(T2(t)) = 0, T1(0) = 1, (D(T1))(0) = 0, T2(0) = 1, (D(T2))(0) = 1];
sol := dsolve(Sys, type = numeric, range = 0 .. 20, output = listprocedure);
odeplot(sol, [T1(t), T2(t)], 0 .. 20, refine = 1); 
TT1, TT2 := op(subs(sol, [T1(t), T2(t)])); 
f := proc (t) options operator, arrow; pointplot([cos(TT1(t)), sin(TT1(t))], color = blue, symbol = solidcircle, symbolsize = 25) end proc; 
p := proc (t) options operator, arrow; pointplot([cos(TT2(t)), sin(TT2(t))], color = red, symbol = solidcircle, symbolsize = 25) end proc;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's Matlab code? It looks like Maple...

Comment: This is not MATLAB for sure (or it is so riddled with syntax errors that this is almost undebuggable). Please [edit] your question to be on-topic and properly tagged, meaning a question, which you haven't asked here, state why this code is insufficient and what you have tried to get it working for more than one mass, and do tag the correct language. You won't get any help this way, as this simply is not MATLAB and those are the only folks who'll see this question.

Comment: @Bebs, sorry, I was tired and accidentally clicked on similar "ma"-word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided no explanation of the way your equations are intended to model a physical system, which is not helpful.

So I have made some guesses about your intentions and your model. Please don't blame me if my guesses are not on the mark.

```
restart;
with(plots):

Sys := [2*(diff(T1(t), t, t))+cos(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T2(t), t, t))
    +sin(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T2(t), t))^2+19.6*sin(T1(t)) = 0,
    diff(T2(t), t, t)+cos(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T1(t), t, t))
    -sin(T1(t)-T2(t))*(diff(T1(t), t))+9.8*sin(T2(t)) = 0,
    T1(0) = 1, (D(T1))(0) = 0, T2(0) = 1, (D(T2))(0) = 1]:

sol := dsolve(Sys, numeric, range = 0 .. 20, output = listprocedure):

TT1, TT2 := op(subs(sol, [T1(t), T2(t)])):

fp := t -> plots:-display(
          pointplot([sin(TT1(t))+sin(TT2(t)), -cos(TT1(t))-cos(TT2(t))],
                    color = red, symbol = solidcircle, symbolsize = 25),
          pointplot([sin(TT1(t)), -cos(TT1(t))],
                    color = blue, symbol = solidcircle, symbolsize = 25),
          plottools:-line([0,0],[sin(TT1(t)), -cos(TT1(t))]),
          plottools:-line([sin(TT1(t)), -cos(TT1(t))],
                          [sin(TT1(t))+sin(TT2(t)), -cos(TT1(t))-cos(TT2(t))]),
          scaling=constrained
       ):

animate(fp, [t], t=0..10, frames=200);
```

[image]

I don't know whether this kind of stacked view is what you're after, as a representation of the position of "both" masses. It's not really clear what you mean by that.

But perhaps the key thing is that, if the two-element lists you are using within your `pointplot` calls represent (displacement) vectors, then you can get the stacked/cumulative effect on the second mass by adding those two vectors elementwise. That's how the red point gets its position in my animation. Hopefully this will allow you to get the cumulative effect with both masses, in your own choice of representation.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I need.